# javascript immediate function initialization

Tags: javascript

In the code below, my `return` function inside the other function doesn't get run right away, but the first function is. My goal is to have the whole function running immediately.

```
var windowCheck = (function () {
                    var switcher = false;
                    return function () {
                        console.log(switcher);
                        if ($window.innerWidth > 480) {
                            if (!switcher) {
                                element.perfectScrollbar({
                                    wheelSpeed: scope.wheelSpeed || 50,
                                    wheelPropagation: $parse(attrs.wheelPropagation)() || false,
                                    minScrollbarLength: $parse(attrs.minScrollbarLength)() || false
                                });
                                console.log('Plugin On');
                                switcher = true;
                            }

                        }
                        else {
                            if (switcher) {
                                console.log('Plugin Off');
                                element.perfectScrollbar('destroy');
                                switcher = false;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function does indeed run the first time -- an anonymous function runs and it's result is --

Another function!

This 'second' function is then assigned to the value of `windowCheck`.

And `windowCheck` won't run until called.

Comment: ok, how about when I add another set of parentheses after the returning function, it actually runs but then i can't call it again.

Comment: Corrrect.. because when you add the second set of parens you are causeing it to invoke, and the return value of that function, `undefined` i this case, gets assigned to `windowCheck`.   IIFE's are great for one-shot runs, but if you want to be able to run it a second time, you have to assign it to a variable and then call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run it after defining it and avoid all the anonymous function mess:

```
var windowCheck = function() {
    ...
}
windowCheck();
```

Comment: They are using the closure to house the `switcher` variable and keep it private.  So, there is some point to the closure.

Answer (score 0):

The code as you have it now defines the `windowCheck` function and uses a closure to house a private `switcher` variable.  That is all fine.  If you want the function that gets defined to be executed, then you just have to add this to the end of what you already have:

```
windowCheck();
```

in order to actually execute it immediately.